# Make a textbox generate text files like t1.txt t2.txt t3.txt, and so on

Tags: php, forms, post, text, methods

I have this code on my website:

```
        <form name="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "t.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a);
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

The thing i'd like it to do is that when there is already a t.txt, it'll create a t2.txt, and then t3.txt and so on, so it doesen't overwrite the text in the previous t.txt.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function which checks if the file exist..

```
function checkFile($x) {


  $file = "t".$x.".txt";

  if (file_exists($file) {

    checkFile(($x+1));

  } else {

    //make a file

  }

}
```

EDIT:

```
 if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) {

  $a = $_POST['text_box']; 
  $myFile = "t.txt";

  if (!file_exists($myFile)) {

    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 
    fwrite($fh, $a); 
    fclose($fh);

  } else {

    checkFile(1,$a);

  }

}

function checkFile($x,$a) {


  $file = "t".$x.".txt";

  if (file_exists($file)) {

    checkFile(($x+1),$a);

  } else {

    $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 
    fwrite($fh, $a); 
    fclose($fh);

  }

}
```

Comment: Could you add my code into that for me? My page wont load when i do it.

Comment: My webpage still won't load. In google chrome it says that it may be misconfigured. :/

Answer (score 0):

For a non-recursive solution:

```
$count = 0;
while (true)
{
    if (!file_exists("t".++$count.".txt") 
    {
        write to file here...
        break;
    }
}
```